# Get Date Taken for NEF format images

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

I have a function that gets the date taken value for pictures in JPEG format. I've run into a problem with the NEF Nikon raw format. In Windows 8 I can see the Date Taken value if I add the column to the Windows Explorer detail view.

The error I receive when the following is executed is "This codec does not support the specified property."

```
public string GetDate(FileInfo f)
        {
            string date;

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(f.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            { 
                BitmapSource img = BitmapFrame.Create(fs);
                BitmapMetadata md = (BitmapMetadata)img.Metadata;
                date = md.DateTaken;
            }

            return date;
        }
```

I tried the suggestion in this [article](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84474/reading-writing-and-photo-metadata/) that is referenced in similar SO answers, using the GetQuery method for BitmapMetadata, but that returned the same error, here was the code I used:

```
public string GetDate(FileInfo f)
        {
            string date;

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(f.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            { 
                BitmapSource img = BitmapFrame.Create(fs);
                BitmapMetadata md = (BitmapMetadata)img.Metadata;
                object t = Mdata.GetQuery("System.Photo.DateTaken");
            }

            return date;
        }
```

I'm deploying this to a Windows 8 PC, so I don't mind a Windows 8 or .NET 4.5 only solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue, I had to install the [Nikon NEF Codec](http://www.nikonimglib.com/nefcodec/) on my PC. What I'm confused about is that Windows 8 is able to display NEF images and provide metadata from EXIF such as Date Taken, out of the box. My gut tells me that there is a Windows or .NET library I could use that I could obtain the same information without installing the codec. Unfortunately I'm pressed for time and don't have time to dive deeper.

Comment: I am in the same boat as you, just in Canon side of things. Jpegs are just fine, but CR2 images are problem. Windows Explorer gets the DateTaken without any issues, but fails when tried via WIC.

Answer (score 0):

Java has a much more versatile open source library here: [metadata-extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor)

I just imported their library and it worked like a charm with `NEF` files, plus it supports many more file extensions.