# Conversion from string "‎8/‎5/‎2014" to type 'Date' is not valid

Tags: vb.net, date, visual-studio-2012, date-conversion

My code has retrieved the "Date Taken" property from an image file and stored it as a string. It then passes that string back to the Main Sub where it tries to compare it to an other date (system time). I receive an error saying i can't convert my string date to a Date. (Conversion from string "‎8/‎5/‎2014" to type 'Date' is not valid.)

In the code below there are two commented-out lines. When these lines are executed the program works as expected (the string is converted to a date). The date in the commented-out line matches (visually) the programmatic acquired date exactly; although if i copy and paste from the watch window it will also fail.

```vb
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Globalization

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim topLevelFolder As New DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\amitchell\Desktop\test1\")
        Dim cutoffDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30)
        Dim Dtaken As String
        Dim PassFile
        Dim Dtaken2

        Using outputFile As New StreamWriter("output_file.txt")
            For Each currentFile In topLevelFolder.EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                PassFile = currentFile.FullName
                Dtaken = GetProperty(PassFile, 12)
                'Dtaken = "8/5/2014"
                'Dtaken2 = IsDate(Dtaken)
                If Dtaken > cutoffDate Then
                    outputFile.WriteLine(currentFile.FullName)
                End If
            Next
        End Using

    End Sub

    Function GetProperty(strFile, n)
        Dim objShell As Object
        Dim objFolder
        Dim objFolderItem
        Dim i
        Dim strPath
        Dim strName
        Dim intPos

        On Error GoTo ErrHandler

        intPos = InStrRev(strFile, "\")
        strPath = Left(strFile, intPos)
        strName = Mid(strFile, intPos + 1)
        objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
        objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(CObj(strPath))
        objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(strName)
        If Not objFolderItem Is Nothing Then
            GetProperty = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, n)
            GetProperty = Left(GetProperty, InStrRev(GetProperty, " ") - 1)
            GetProperty = Left(GetProperty, InStrRev(GetProperty, " ") - 1)
        End If

ExitHandler:
        objFolderItem = Nothing
        objFolder = Nothing
        objShell = Nothing
        Exit Function

ErrHandler:
        MsgBox(Err.Description, vbExclamation)
        Resume ExitHandler
    End Function


End Module
```

Comment: Why not keep the date as a DateTime instead of storing it as a string? I also suggest turning OPTION STRICT ON to help you with this combination of VB.NET and what looks like VBscript.

Comment: Please don't write vb.net as if it were vb6.

Comment: When I set Function GetProperty(strFile, n) As DateTime I recieve the same error: Conversion from string "‎8/‎5/‎2014 ‏‎4:21 PM" to type 'Date' is not valid.

I am not sure which parts of this code are VB.NET vs VBscript
I will look for and turn on this option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date string you provided in one of the comments contains three `U+0000` characters at the start of each date portion `(?8/?5/?2014)` where the `?` denote occurences of `U+0000`

You'll need to strip these out in order to make the date work.

Comment: How would i remove these extra characters? I tried using string manipulation tools but they act is if there are no extra characters.

Example:
Left(Dtaken, InStrRev(Dtaken, "?") - 1)

Comment: They're not actually `?` marks. You could just use Regexp to replace all characters that aren't a number or a /.

Comment: I am sure that Joel's solution is the better solution but this is the one I was able to get to work. I used `Dtaken = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Dtaken, "[^\d /]", "")`

Answer (score 1):

That code makes me sad. It follows a number of conventions that made sense for the vb6/vbscript era, but aren't so good for .Net code. The result is that the bulk of the code is replicating work that's handled for you (and done better) by the .Net Framework. I will give you kudos for embracing `Using` blocks, so there's hope.

This code makes better use of the .Net Framework. It completely sidesteps your issue by never rendering any date value as a string.

```vb
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim topLevelFolder As New DirectoryInfo("C:\Users\amitchell\Desktop\test1\")
        Dim cutoffDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30).Date

        Using outputFile As New StreamWriter("output_file.txt")
            Dim files = topLevelFolder.EnumerateFileSystemInfos("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).
                   Where( Function(f) f.CreationTime > cutoffDate )
            For Each file in files
                outputFile.WriteLine(file.FullName)
            Next file
        End Using
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Your code is certainly much more elegant than mine but it works based on the CreationTime. It is important for my purposes that it be keyed of off the DateTaken property. Also your code picks up folders, which i can eliminate later.

Also I am sorry that my code makes you sad... but it makes me happy that you see a glimmer of hope for me.

Comment: Or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13940436/get-date-taken-for-nef-format-images

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why one `String` would work where another wouldn't. You would normally have to convert a `String` to `DateTime` in order to compare them. Try the following:

```
Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(Dtaken)
```

And then

```
If dt > cutoffDate Then
```

EDIT: I voted Joel's answer as most probable solution, but I'll keep this here for the sake of comments attached.

Comment: I get the same error that I have recieved from many other attempts to correct this issue:

String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

This is the value of Dtaken as copied from the Watch Window:
‎8/‎5/‎2014

I can not see any reason that that string is not recognized as a date yet this one is:
8/5/2014

Comment: I copied them into Notepad++ - The first string is 8/?5/?2014 and the second string is 8/5/2014

Comment: Thank you for finding the difference.
I have tried adding the following line:
Dtaken = Date.ParseExact(Dtaken, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)

But this had no affect.